# Grepping output from Codesign

Tags: terminal, code-signing

I am trying to filter codesign command output using the following command, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
codesign -d --entitlements - /Applications/Safari.app | grep -i "*sandbox"
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't seem to work"? What does it do, and how is that different from what you want?

Comment: @gordon I was expecting the output to include `<key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>`, but got this instead `Executable=/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari`